# Why tomcat on linux needs to build APR and not download

Tags: linux, ssl, tomcat, https

I am trying to install [APR](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/apr.html) on Ubuntu Linux.
I found that tomcat provides a [downloadable APR package for windows](http://tomcat.apache.org/download-native.cgi)
but i cannot find a downloadable version for Linux.
The tomcat site gives instructions about how to build the APR sources.

My first question is: Why can't i download the APR extension, and instead i need to compile it locally?

And my second question is: Can i distribute Tomcat lib to other machines with a pre-built APR?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just install this stuff from the package repositories, not from the project web sites.

As an example, the APR is available as `libapr1` (and many related stuff) in the Ubuntu repositories. The same is true for Tomcat etc.

As long as you can possibly avoid it, never install anything not from the repos to keep your life simple (and make use of the advantages of the package system and the maintainers hard work to keep you up to date and secure).